# Filling a slice of interface type given as argument (e.g., implement a ScanAll for database/sql)

Tags: go

How could we implement a function which would return all rows resulting from a SQL query and convert them to `dest` which is an interface array (may not work as `Scan`) ?

I assume the destination array would have to be given as an argument to the function. But then, I still do not know how I am supposed to complete the implementation:

```
func GetAll(query string, dest interface{}) error {

  rows, err := s.db.Query(query)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  defer rows.Close()

  for rows.Next() {
    var destRow ??? /* do not have a type. using reflect.TypeOf(dest).Elem()? */
    err := rows.Scan(&destRow)
    if err != nil {
      return err
    }
    dest = append(dest, destRow) /* would even compile? */
  }
  return nil
}
```

It does not look like much different from what `json.Unmarshal` have to do actually...

Comment: Have you taken a look at the source of `json.Unmarshal`?

Comment: rows.Scan takes an argument for each column. Can I assume from the code in your question that you are querying for a single column?  If so, I'll whip up an answer.  If there are multiple columns, describe what you plan to pass to `dest` and how columns are mapped to whatever is in there.

Comment: @Adrian : Yes without being able to find the answer to my question actually. I am not a Go expert, so I may not understand some important part.

Comment: @ThunderCat you're right, let's say it was for the exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the [reflect package](https://godoc.org/reflect). Call the function with a pointer to a slice.

```
func GetAll(query string, dest interface{}) error {

    // Return error if dest is not a pointer to a slice.
    slice := reflect.ValueOf(dest)
    if slice.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return errors.New("dest must be pointer")
    }
    slice = slice.Elem()
    if slice.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        return errors.New("dest must be pointer to struct")
    }

    rows, err := db.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        // Create a new slice element. The variable elementp holds a 
        // pointer to the new element.
        elementp := reflect.New(slice.Type().Elem())

        err := rows.Scan(elementp.Interface())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // Append the element to the slice.
        slice.Set(reflect.Append(slice, elementp.Elem()))
    }
    return nil
}
```

The above code works with standard database/sql package when the query result has a single column and dest is a pointer to a slice of a type appropriate for that column.  Here's an example:

```
var names []string
if err := GetAll(db, "select name from people", &names); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

This code should also work with a database package that supports scanning multiple columns to a struct.